# Set of triple-primes satisfying a certain equation

Tags: number-theory

Is there a set of triple-primes satisfying the following equation?

$p_{1}p_{2}+p_{2}p_{3}+p_{3}p_{1}+p_{1}+p_{2}+p_{3}=2^{\beta},\,p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}=2^{\alpha}-1,\,\alpha >\beta .$

I have checked the first 11 numbers that no one satisfy the above condition. It's easy to check that when all the prime numbers $p_i$ are in the form of $4k+3$, then we have $p_i=2^{s_i}k_{i}+2^{s_i}-1$

Comment: See also at [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234623/set-of-triple-primes-satisfying-a-certain-equation).

Answer (score 0):

An example is given by $(p_1,p_2,p_3)=(3,11,31)$. Indeed, we have
$$
p_1p_2p_3=1023=2^{10}-1, \; p_1p_2+p_2p_3+p_3p_1+p_1+p_2+p_3=512=2^9.
$$
Indeed also $\alpha=10>9=\beta$.

Comment: i have got it.above

Answer (score 0):

REMARK.-Even for not prime integers $a,b,c$ it seems there are no solutions. In fact,the problem can be reformulated (without the restriction "primes") as follows:

**Solve the diophantine equation $$xyz+1=2^a(xy+xz+yz+x+y+z)\qquad (*)$$ where $a$ is an integer greater or equal than $1$.**

Till the exponent $a=20$ so $a^{20}=1 048 576$ only trivial solution $(x,y,z)=(-1,-1,-1)$ and its trivial variations because of symmetry are given by calculators, excepting for the exponent $a=1$ in which there is the non-trivial solution $(-9,-7,1)$

Hence a way to prove the question could be to prove $(*)$ for integers.

Comment: thought$(x,y,z)=(3,11,31)$is an answer to it,that is only on  the loose condition.if we let $\beta\leq \alpha -2 $,and then what we can say about it.

Comment: Your example is for $a=1$; it is "similar" to $(-9,-7,1)$ so the problem remains intact.